# Is it possible to get no solution from an optimal stopping problem

Tags: statistics, optimization, applications, optimal-control, decision-theory

I recently read about the 37-percent rule as the solution to the secretary problem.
It says

> To have the highest chance of getting the best applicant from a pool of applicants, you should interview the first 37 percent but rejecting all of them. After this time of "calibration" you should choose the first applicant that is better than everyone you interviewed before.

Im now asking myself what happens if we dont find a person that is better than the best we rejected in the phase after calibration. Does this mean the solution is we dont hire anyone? And if so how should the rule be modified if we are forced to hire someone in the end?

Comment: I believe the 37% is on average still optimal, even if none are better and you would have to hire the last one (that probability is probably quite low). Though, I would have to look up a reference to be sure.